# point go a round way but address changed

Tags: c++, pointers, queue, memory-address

I implement a queue myself. when testing, I expect the dequeue to reutrn when the queue is empty by testing if the tail pointer point to the head node. However, the address of the head node and the one pointer point are different when the point indeed points to the head, hence the queue never stop dequeue even if there is nothing in it.
This confuse me a lot. Any suggestion on this?
thanks a lot.

```
//header
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

struct node
{
int val;
struct node* next;

};

class queue
{
private:
    node head;
    node* tail;
public:
    queue();
    void enqueue(int val);
    void dequeue(int& holder, bool& v);
};





#endif
// queue.cpp
#include "queue.h"

using namespace std;
queue::queue()
{
    tail = &head;

}
void queue::enqueue(int val)
{
    node* tmp = new node;
    tmp->val = val;
    if(tail == &head)
    {
            tail = tmp;
            tmp->next = &head;
            head.next = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
            node* holder = head.next;
            head.next = tmp;
            tmp->next = &head;
            holder->next = tmp;
    }
}

void queue::dequeue(int& holder,bool& v)
{

    if(tail == &head)
   {
            v = false;
   }
    else
    {
            node* cur = tail;
            tail = tail->next;
            holder = cur->val;
            v = true;
            delete cur;

    }

}
//test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "queue.h"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main()
{
int ary[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

queue myq;
for(int i = 0;i< sizeof(ary);i++)
{
    myq.enqueue(ary[i]);
}
int tmp;
bool flag;
for(int i = 0;i<=7;i++)
{
    myq.dequeue(tmp,flag);
    if(flag)
            cout<<"number is "<<tmp<<endl;
    else
            cout<<"queue empty"<<endl;
}
return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: First question here, please read [How to ask Questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) esp, what to do when you get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could give you the exact fix, but that would teach you absolutely nothing, you'd just copy and paste that into your code and go away do something else. So I'm going to help you with a line of code to add to show what the current value of &head is, and thus help identify what the actual problem is...

Add this line to enqueue (at the top of the function) and dequeue:

```
     std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": " << &head << std::endl;
```

It will print the name of the function and the address off head. (You may need to include iostream as well)

Pay particular attention to how many printouts you get!

Comment: thanks Mats, sizeof(ary) fetch me 20 which is the number of byte that array occupied actually. Its a stupid question, I admit. I like your way of teaching.

Answer (score 0):

Working code below: (Learn to use a debugger)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//header
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

struct node {
    int val;
    struct node* next;

};

class queue {
private:
    struct node* head;
    struct node* tail;
public:
    queue();
    void enqueue(int val);
    void dequeue(int& holder, bool& v);
};

#endif

using namespace std;
queue::queue() {
    tail = NULL;
    head = NULL;

}
void queue::enqueue(int val) {
    node* tmp = new node;

    tmp->val = val;

    if (head == NULL && NULL == tail) {//No nodes Empty
        head = tail = tmp;
        tmp->next = NULL;

    }else if (tail == head) { //Single node
        tail = tmp;
        tmp->next = head;
        head->next = tmp;
    } else {
        tail->next = tmp;
        tmp->next = head;
        tail = tmp;
    }
}

void queue::dequeue(int& holder, bool& v) {
    if (NULL == tail || NULL == head) {
        v = false;
        return;
    } else if (tail == head) {// single node
        holder = head->val;
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        v = true;
    } else { //more than one node
        //Go to the last but one node and chop the tail
        node* cur = head;
        while (cur->next != tail)
            cur = cur->next;

        cur->next = head;
        holder = tail->val;
        delete tail;
        tail = cur;
        v = true;
    }
    return;
}

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main() {
    int ary[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    queue myq;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        myq.enqueue(ary[i]);
    }

    int tmp;
    bool flag;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        myq.dequeue(tmp, flag);
        if (flag) {
            cout << "number is " << tmp << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "queue empty" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks SparKot, it works. I misused sizeof operator. Yours is another way to way.